# Logging to a dynamically created WinForms control using the configuration file with log4net

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, controls, log4net

The case is as follows: I have created a custom control that represents a camera connection and its properties in which there is a ListBox. I instantiate this custom control dynamically at runtime. How often I instantiate it depends on how many cameras are configured. I therefore only find out the number of cameras at runtime. I currently use `LogManager.GetLogger()` to create a logger of type `ILog` for each connection, in which I log the events of the specific connection.

Now I want to display the log messages of each logger in the ListBox of the corresponding custom control. At the same time, I want to be able to configure this type of logger via the configuration file. It would be ideal if I could configure each logger specifically. However, I imagine this would be difficult considering that the number of cameras and therefore the number of loggers is only known at runtime. Therefore, a "general" configuration of this type of logger would be sufficient for me, which is then simply adopted for every logger of this type.

I have already found ways of logging messages in a control, but I always need the name of the control for this. Otherwise, logging can also be configured completely programmatically, but this does not correspond to my wish to configure logging via the configuration file.

Can this case be realized with the help of the functionalities of log4net?

My application's target framework is .NET 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a base logger in a log4net.config I imagine something along these lines:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="GeneralAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs/camera_connection.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="CameraBaseLogger">
        <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

When you instantiate your custom control for a camera connection, create a logger for it dynamically using a naming convention that relates the logger to the specific camera/connection. Use the base logger as a reference for its configuration.

```
// Assuming 'cameraId' uniquely identifies each camera/connection
string loggerName = $"CameraLogger_{cameraId}";
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("CameraBaseLogger", loggerName);

logger.Info("whatever should be logged");
```

than you use a memoryAppender or a custom appender and than poll or react to an event to update the UI from the UI thread since you want to log messages in a listBox

```
public class ListBoxAppender : log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton
{
    public string ControlName { get; set; }
    public Form FormInstance { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (FormInstance.InvokeRequired)
        {
            FormInstance.Invoke(new Action(() => Append(loggingEvent)));
            return;
        }

        ListBox listBox = FormInstance.Controls.Find(ControlName, true).FirstOrDefault() as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent));
        }
    }
}
```

**Concrete Example of logging**

assume we have a custom control that represents a camera connection.
This control includes a **ListBox** for displaying logs
using System.Windows.Forms;

```
public class CameraConnectionControl : UserControl
{
    public ListBox LogListBox { get; private set; }

    public CameraConnectionControl()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private void InitializeComponents()
    {
        LogListBox = new ListBox();
        LogListBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(LogListBox);
    }
}
```

**Than we dynamically create the control and logger**
In your form or wherever you dynamically create these controls based on the number of cameras, you would do something like this:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        // Example initialization - this could be triggered by detecting cameras, a button click, etc.
        InitializeCameraControls(3); // Assume 3 cameras for this example
    }

    private void InitializeCameraControls(int numberOfCameras)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
        {
            // Create the custom control
            CameraControl cameraControl = new CameraControl();
            cameraControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            this.Controls.Add(cameraControl);

            // Instantiate and configure the ListBoxAppender for this control
            ListBoxAppender appender = new ListBoxAppender
            {
                TargetListBox = cameraControl.LogListBox
            };

            // Create a logger instance for this camera/control
            string cameraId = $"Camera_{i}";
            ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(cameraId);

            // Programmatically add the appender to the logger
            log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger log = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger;
            log.AddAppender(appender);
            log.Repository.Configured = true;

            // Example logging
            logger.Info($"Camera {i} initialized.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Key Points**

1. Each CameraControl instance has its own ListBox for logging.
2. A ListBoxAppender is created for each CameraControl and is assigned the control’s ListBox.
3. A unique logger is instantiated for each camera, and the corresponding ListBoxAppender is added to it, allowing log messages to be directed to the correct ListBox.

Hope this is more clear

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have now understood the idea of defining the logger in the configuration file and using the logger in the code based on the logger name.

However, it is not yet clear to me how I should use the ListBoxAppender you suggested and, in particular, when I should instantiate it. Can you give me a concrete example? In addition, I don't know the name of the ListBox. Would it be possible to assign a ListBox directly to the appender into which it should log? I already have it available for each of my custom controls.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification, this is exactly how I'd have done it. However, there is one point I don't understand: In your concrete example you don't use any reference of the logger named `CameraBaseLogger` that you defined and used in your first example to get the logger. As a result, I get an `InvalidOperationException` as soon as `RenderLoggingEvent` in `ListBoxAppender` is executed telling me "A layout must be set". To me, this indicates that the exact configuration your passed in your first example that also defines a layout, is missing here.

Comment: As soon as I instantiate a logger like you did in your first example using `CameraBaseLogger`, I get an exception telling me "Repository [CameraBaseLogger] is NOT defined".

Comment: And yes, of course I could configure the missing layout programmatically but right at this point I want to be able to configure all these aspects via the configuration file. I hope this makes my thoughts more clear now.